# Tomar todos los datos de un form e insertarlos a la base de datos sin conocer los nombres de los campos

Tags: php, mysqli

alguien sabe sobre como enviar un formulario desde php y al recibir los datos via $_POST poder ingresar esos datos a la base de datos, sin saber cuantos campos son, pero que el nombre de los campos son los mismos de las columnas dela tabla en la base de datos?

es decir, is se enviar 4 campos en el formulario al recibir se agreguen algo asi como:

> **query("INSERT INTO tabla (?, ?, ?, ?) values ('?', '?', '?', '?')");**

Gracias

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es algo como lo que hacen los ORM (Eloquent por ejemplo) pero incluso ellos ya tienen previamente la estructura de la tabla o DB. Cual es el problema por el que no puedas definir en tu query los campos??

Comment: Prueba con `array_keys()` o un simple `foreach($_POST as $key=>$dato){}` para construir tu query o pasarle las variables a `bind_param()`. Recuerda que debes intentar algo para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: @OCHOA tengo muchas tablas que se deben actualizar o agregar datos, y los formularios son en distintas cantidades y de campos, la idea era que al enviar serialize y el mismo nombre de los campos los tome como nombres de las columnas para de alguna forma automatizar el envio de un formulario y no tener que especificar cada campo

Comment: No es tan complicado lo que quieres hacer. Simplemente debes tomar de `$_POST` los nombres de las claves, para escribir con ellos la primera parte del `INSERT INTO`, luego pones los marcadores según la cantidad de columnas que tenga `$_POST` creando así una consulta preparada. Finalmente, pasas los valores de `$_POST` con la función de vinculación y haces el `execute()`. Ya tienes la idea general, ahora, intenta un código y nos dices en qué falla y podremos ayudarte mejor. El principal problema en preguntas sin código es que ni siquiera sabemos qué herramientas estás usando, pues hay varias.

Comment: Cuando hablo de varias herramientas, me refiero a si usarás `mysqli` o `PDO` para hacer esto, porque el código será ligeramente distinto entre una herramienta y otra. Otra cosa importante es saber si entre los datos que se van a recibir por `$_POST` habrá alguno destinado a una columna del tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT`, o, si lo habrá en algunos casos y en otros no. De ser así, deberás explicar qué estrategia usarás en tu formulario para identificar esos campos. Por ejemplo, podrías llamar **siempre** a esa clave `id`, para saber que es un `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Faltan esos detalles en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano uso mysqli, PDO no lo dominio, todas las tablas tienen un AUTO_INCREMENT para ir agregadon elementos y q automaticamente incremente id, la idea es agregar elementos a la tabla, por el momento no actualizar y los valores se reciben por $_POST, no coloco codigo por que tengo la idea (ñlo que estoy preguntando) pero no se como ponerlo en marcha, gracias